# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories

Tags: java, android, directory

I used until now next code to download required files:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                                        request.setDescription("descriere");
                                        request.setTitle(mName);
                                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyDirectory/MyFiles", mFile);
```

But after I updated my android version to 10 I get now next error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories
```

for

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyDirectory/MyFiles", mFile);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: file is downloaded on Android/data and not on public directory

Comment: change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 29 to 28

Comment: Thanx its working after change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 29 to 28

Comment: You will eventually move to targetsdkversion 29.

Here is what you need to do.

To Store file in External App-Specific Directory,
Call
`.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName)`


To Store file in External Public Directory,
call
`.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName)`